# Mails invalid signature because of encoding of periods in quoted printable

Tags: email, encoding

I‘m sending a mail encoded with quoted printable encoding that contains some dots `.`. There is a problem with a specific mailserver/customer. For some reason, they receive the mail in such a form that each dot is encoded as `=2E` ultimately breaking the signature.

What system could possibly do this? It‘s not defined in the standard to encode dots as well. What would be the best practice solution? Encode every dot to prevent the system from converting? Did anybody of you encounter this problem already?

I'm sending the mails via python using the `email` package. The quoted-printable encoding will happen using the `set_content` method in python3. The problem only occurs for a special mail server. Here is an example email:

Mail after leaving my program:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

<!DOCTYPE html><html><h1>Test Email</h1><p>This is a test email. Showing En=
coding of points in quoted-printable.</p></html>
```

Test mail received by the mail client:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

<!DOCTYPE html><html><h1>Test Email</h1><p>This is a test email=2E Showing =
Encoding of points in quoted-printable=2E</p></html>
```

Comment: How do you send the data? Using established mail clients or libraries or by implementing your own client? And could you provide a minimal example (complete mail, incl. MIME headers - both what you deliver and what customer gets) which shows the reproducible problem, so that one can see what exactly is happening here?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I provided an example. The messages are sent using python and the following mail wrapper: https://github.com/CZ-NIC/envelope. The quoted printable encoding inside this wrapper is based on quopri and is done during set_content() method of the EmailMessage class from the email package of python3

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks. I know for sure the signature is valid after leaving my program. I logged the messages and tested with openssl. What do you think about sending the mails as 8BIT? Iwas thinking about either base64 or 8Bit as a workaround

Comment: Since the signature is done on the encoded part, recoding this part (as done here) will break the signature.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you for your help. Sorry, but i have a basic question: Why isn't base64 used in the first place by most mails? Sure it's unnecessary encoding but these days it shouldn't matter right? Is it considered uncommon to encode base64 for mail bodies?

Comment: It's all about historic evolution. To maintain compatibility with traditional pure-ASCII mail and transport, MIME and encoding were added in the first place. For text with only few non-ASCII characters quoted-printable is the more efficient encoding, for more binary data base64. That's why traditionally most implementations use quoted-printable for text while base64 for attachments.